# Difference between calibration and tuning

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "calibration" and "tuning"?

Comment: Example: 'Calibration is the process used to ensure mass accuracy; tuning is used to make sure that the instrument is working well for a particular sample.' https://blog.sepscience.com/liquidchromatography/hplc-solutions-5-lc-ms-calibration-vs.-tuning

Comment: @Weoathtocreation.  I’m not sure I agree. This is certainly the way it is used in the context you cite, but the usage is very particular to that instrument. The words can be used in other ways too.

Comment: To calibrate is used in the context of measuring equipment. Calibration is done by reference to an absolute standard. Calibration requires the discovery of, and compensation for, irregularities in measurement. Calibration can also mean to place marks on a scale such that they coincide with a convenient or standard unit of measurement.

To tune is usually used of musical instruments and means to adjust the output of the instrument to a given point on the musical scale. 

Thus the essential difference is that we calibrate for a measurement, and tune for output.

Comment: You can read the different definitions and see that the main difference is that *calibrate* refers to adjustments made to an instrument for measurement (or that includes some aspect of measurement as part of its operation) including a ranged device of some sort. While *tune* (for the meaning most related to calibrate) refers to adjustment to improve output efficiency, speed, performance, resolution, etc. There will be points of intersection between the separate meanings too, so they become synonyms in particular contexts.

Comment: Examples of apparent overlap - both of these refer to adjusting for optimal performance but each uses a different word: *The clinicians tune the cardiac device well before surgery to ensure it performs optimally in the patient.* AND *Calibration is when we adjust... the [ignition interlock device] to ensure that it is operating at peak performance, with utmost accuracy.* On the surface these examples make “tune” and ”calibrate” seem like synonyms but presumably behind the scenes the details of the adjustments reveal why in each case one word is chosen over another.

Comment: You calibrate against a reference standard. The purpose is to set up the device so it provides standardized results. You tune a device to a particular application. The purpose is to provide improved discrimination at some region of interest.

Comment: @PhilSweet I think your explanation is insightful and am happy to accept it once you add it as an answer.

Comment: ["You can tune a piano but you can't tuna fish."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can_Tune_a_Piano,_but_You_Can%27t_Tuna_Fish)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calibrate against a reference standard. The purpose is to set up the device so it provides standardized results. You tune a device to a particular application. The purpose is to provide improved discrimination at some region of interest.